# If...Then... syntax issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to write an app that calculates sick/vacation days and how much an employee has available in either category. In my Employee model, **vacation_days** is a value determined by their hire-on date, and **sick_days** is the same for all employees, and are separate "pools." My latest roadblock is trying to determine how to have their time-off being subtracted from the appropriate pool.

Here's my Employee model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  def remaining_vacation_days
    vacation_days - vacation_days_used
  end

  def remaining_sick_days
    sick_days - sick_days_used
  end

  def vacation_days_used 
    if Furlough.description == "Vacation"
      Furlough.duration
    end 
  end

  def sick_days_used
    if Furlough.description == "Sick"
    Furlough.duration
    end
  end
```

There's a string column named *:description* in the model that handles the date ranges (named **Furlough**), and the form is a radio-button where the only two options are *'Sick'* and *'Vacation'*. However, I'm having issues with getting the syntax right in the **Employee** model:

```
SyntaxError in Employees#index

Showing /Users/ryrythefrenchfry/rails_projects/time_tracker/app/views/employees/index.html.erb where line #28 raised:

/Users/ryrythefrenchfry/rails_projects/time_tracker/app/models/furlough.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
  end
     ^
Extracted source (around line #28):

25:     <td></td>
26:     <td><%= employee.years_employed %></td>
27:     <td></td>
28:     <td><%= employee.remaining_sick_days %></td>
29:     <td></td>
30:     <td><%= employee.remaining_vacation_days %></td>
31:     <td></td>
```

When I comment out *def vacation_days_used* and *def sick_days_used* it goes through, so I know that's where my problem is, but I just don't have a good enough understanding of what I'm doing yet to find the answer in documentation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: the error is in your furlough.rb file, so you will need to show that file, not the employee.rb  file.

Comment: @fotanus Until more information is available this is unrelated to Rails and is rather a Ruby code issue.

Comment: Oh geez. Yeah, I must have cut out an end in my Furlough.model. Now my issue is completely different. Should I just delete this post and start over the new question or do I edit it? What's good practice?

Comment: @RyanClark If it's a totally different issue and unrelated to a missing `end` it's clearly a new question.

Comment: I would just create a new post, potentially reference it from here? Is duration and description static methods on Furlough.  My guess is they need to be accessed through an association on the employee model (Employee has_[one|many] :furloughs ?

Comment: well, technically, your first problem was solved with this thread. so, i would say: a) edit your question to what was earlier (the missing `end`) b) then accept an answer c) post new question for new problem

Comment: Thanks for all of your help guys/gals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one more `end` for the class. Add it as the last line in your model file.

```
  def sick_days_used
    if Furlough.description == "Sick"
      Furlough.duration
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Whoops, that was a copy-paste error. I do have that end in my actual model.

Comment: ... But not in the Furlough model. God, I really buggered this question up! :(

Answer (score 1):

You miss an "end" at the last line of your code.

```
  def sick_days_used
    if Furlough.description == "Sick"
    Furlough.duration
    end
  end
end
```

It's the one "ending" your class.

Comment: Ack, that was a copy-paste error. I do have that 'end' in my actual model.

Comment: ... But not in the Furlough model. Geez. I'm going to go to my room and think about what I did. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is more Rubyistic(as per your case):

```
def vacation_days_used 
   Furlough.duration if Furlough.description == "Vacation"
end

def sick_days_used
    Furlough.duration if Furlough.description == "Sick"
end
```

Comment: True, but unrelated, and could be served up in a comment.

Comment: this is equivalent to what is there in the question as well.

Comment: As per the OP's scenario this will lower the chance of `end` confliction. Thus I wrote here as answer.

Comment: like @DaveNewton says, the suggestion should probably just be a comment on the OP rather than an answer to it.

Comment: I'm voting this up because I like it. :) Thank you.